# Мнемонічна фраза для запам'ятовування послідовності кольорів веселки?

Tags: фразеологізми, mnemonic

Думаю, багато хто цікавився, який український відповідник російському *Каждый Охотник Желает Знать, Где Сидит Фазан* для легкого запам'ятовування послідовності кольорів веселки.

На офіційному рівні це, звісно, не врегульовано та й навряд чи доцільно.
Проте, небайдужі громадяни вирішили заповнити цю прогалину.

Шляхом голосування на форумі обрано два (залежно від того, оранжевий чи помаранчевий між червоним і жовтим) крилаті вислови, які набрали найбільшу кількість вподобань:

> *Чапля Осінь Жде Завзято, Буде Сани Фарбувати*

(якщо «оранжевий»).

> *Чому Пінгвіни Живуть Зимою Без Своїх Фантазій*

(якщо «помаранчевий»).

У дискусії [за посиланням](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/dlya-ditej/kolori-veselki) можна побачити інші варіанти.

А, може, хто зустрічав у літературі чи посібниках з мови (наприклад, в методичних посібниках для дошкільного/шкільного навчання) іншу мнемонічну фразу, рекомендовану до використання?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Багато разів стикався з тим що статті у Вікіпедії іноді мають досить несподівані відомості. Українська [стаття про веселку](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.96.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.96.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.96.D0.B2) має цілу коллекцію мнемонічних фраз, проте в англійській версії такого нема.

> Чарівниця Осінь Жар-птаху Закликає Бабин Сад Фарбувати
>   Чарівна Оксана Живе Знову Біля Старого Фонтану
>   Чомусь Осіння Журба Завжди Буяє Сумними Фарбами
>   Чоловік Охоче Жінку Заміж Бере Собі Файну
>   Червоні Окуляри Жанки Заважають Бачити Сяйво Фіалки
>   Чому Обізнані Життям Завжди Балакають Смішні Фрази?
>   Червоний Орел Живе За Байраком Серед Фіалок
>   Чапля Осінь Жде Завзято, Буде Сани Фарбувати
>   Чекав Обіду Журналіст. З‘їв Бутерброд — Став Футболіст.
>   Чи Омелько Жити Зможе Без Своїх Фантазій?
>   Чому Олені Живуть Зимою Без Своїх Фантазій?
>   Чим Образив Жайворонка Золотавий Блиск Святкового Феєрверку?

Мені особисто сподобався цей варіант:

> Чи Обжене́ Жваве́нького Зайчи́ська Байдикуватий Ситий Фокстер'єр?

через його подібність до англійської фрази, з веселкою не пов'язаної:

> A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Щодо рекомендацій для дітей, як на мене, тут можуть бути такі критерії:

1. Подібність до вірша (ритмічність, внутрішні рими)
2. Зрозумілі і цікаві для дитячого віку персонажі
3. Наявність дії або взаємодії між персонажами

Подібність до вірша допомагає запам'ятати фразу. Коли що-небудь забувається ритмічність чи наявність рим дозволяють заповнити забуте слово.

Зрозумілі персонажі (і зрозумілі дії) теж допомагають запам'ятати. Спробуйте вивчити пісню на незнайомій мові - слова легко губляться і замінюються співзвучними.

Дія або взаємодія між персонажами додає "екшн" і закріплює смисл того що відбувається.

Також мнемонічним прийомом є використання абсурдних зв'язків для поєднання слів, але я не впевнений що це добре спрацює для дітей (хоча це залежить від віку).

Спробуємо проаналізувати з цієї точки зору "Чи Омелько Жити Зможе Без Своїх Фантазій?":

1. Ритм є, але з натяжкою (слово "фантазій" треба розбити на "фант**а**-з**і**й").
2. Персонаж Омелько - ми про нього нічого не знаємо (напевно що він фантазер?).
3. Дії немає - досить статична ситуація.
4. Абсурдність відсутня.

Тобто фраза має мало мнемонічних "гачків". До того ж "Жити Зможе" легко переставляється у "Зможе Жити" і кольори плутаються.

Тепер проаналізуємо "Чи Обжене́ Жваве́нького Зайчи́ська Байдикуватий Ситий Фокстер'єр?"

1. Є ритм. До того ж він складний і не дозволяє вільно переставляти слова.
2. Персонажі зрозумілі і навіть мають характеристики "жвавий зайчисько" і "байдикуватий фокстер'єр" (хоча слово фокстер'єр для зовсім маленьких дітей може бути не зрозумілим).
3. Є взаємодія між персонажами.
4. Абсурдність відсутня.

Тобто смисл фрази зрозумілий, не абсурдний, фраза має декілька персонажів із типовою (собака женеться за зайцем) активною взаємодією, сусідні слова важко переставити місцями.

Comment: Не буду лукавити. Мені більше до душі: "Чарівна Оксана Живе Знову Біля Старого Фонтану". Та все ж хотілося б дізнатися, чи є рекомендації щодо якогось варіанту. Очевидно, це той випадок, коли немає, і, мабуть, це на краще.

Comment: @Artemix Дякую за викладену думку. Ви маєте рацію. Як для дітей, то варіант із зайчиськом і фокстер'єром видається найприйнятнішим. Хіба що для зовсім маленьких діток трохи складнуватіі слова. Але якщо розмірковувати, що для практичного застосування мнемоніксу дитина вже має розрізняти звуки і виокремлювати перший звук кожного слова фрази, то логічно припустити, що в такому віці слова "байдикуватий" і "фокстер'єр" вже відомі й уживані.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko В "Улюблених віршах" видавництва Абабагаламага є вірш "Дитяча мрія" з такими словами: "Як я хочу теж такого, /
хай би навіть і малого,/
хай би куцого, рудого/
песика!/
Міг би бути фокстер’єром —/
ми б із ним гуляли сквером." (і так далі). Є надія що дітям цього вірша прочитають :)

Comment: Для померанчового кольору можна замінити Обжене на Прожене: Чи Прожене́ Жваве́нького Зайчи́ська Байдикуватий Ситий Фокстер'єр

Comment: Експеримент (на мені) показує що "Чапля Осінь Жде Завзято, Буде Сани Фарбувати" запам'ятовується краще - напевно і ритм простіший і слова. "Байдикуватий Ситий" - декілька "статичних" прикметників підряд, виходить "якійсь" і "якійсь" - важко пригадувати.

Answer (score 3):

На сайті Мова - ДНК нації знайшла цікаву статтю ["Кольори веселки"](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/koloru-veselku)

> Як запам’ятати послідовність кольорів веселки? Пропонуємо спеціальні
>   мнемонічні фрази.
>
> **Варіанти для дітей і дорослих:**
>
> Чому Пінгвіни Живуть Зимою Без Своїх Фантазій
>   Чапля Осінь Жде Завзято, Буде Сани Фарбувати
>   Чарівна Оленка Живе у Заростях Біля Старого Фонтану
>   Чабан Отару Жваво Заганяє, Бо Скоро Фільм
>   Чи Обжене Жвавенького Зайчиська Байдикуватий Ситий Фокстер'єр
>   Чи Одслонить Жінка Зранку Бісову Свою Фіранку?
>
> Варіанти Анатолія Ткаченка:
>
> Чом Овес Жують Зайці?
>   Бо Старанні Фахівці.
>
> Чий Олівчик Жвавий Зрану
>   Грає Струнами Фонтану?
>
> Чий Орган Живе Зорею,
>   Будить Семибарвну Фею?
>
> Чар Очам, Живі Зудари:
>   Грають Сонячні Фанфари!
>
> Чуєш, Отче, Жде Загал:
>   Буде Сонячний Фінал?